# In Groovy, how do I get the list of parameter names for a given job?

Tags: groovy, hudson

In Groovy, I get my hands on a Hudson job:

```
def job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("Rsync library to docs-stage")
```

Now I would like to have a list of the parameter names for that job. Sounds simple, but Googling around isn't getting me there yet. Could someone enlighten me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'n not sure what you mean by "parameter names." As a last resort, you can get the configuration of the job as an XML String:

```
print job.configFile.asString()
```

Since this is XML, you can parse it as needed. Depending on what parameter names you are looking for, you can probably also get them directly in Java. Can you post the XML for what you are looking for? That will help in commenting on a better way.

For the parameters needed by this poster, it is easy to get using Groovy:

```
def params = job.getProperty('hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty')
  .parameterDefinitions

params.each { p -> println "$p.name"}
```

Comment: That is parameters I define. However, I'm going to have to learn a bunch more Groovy to get to the point where I can parse that config.

Comment: <parameterDefinitions>
              <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
                <name>FOO</name>
                <description></description>
                <defaultValue>cd</defaultValue>
              </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
             <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
                <name>BAR</name>
                <description></description>
                <defaultValue>Q18753_01</defaultValue>
              </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
            </parameterDefinitions>

Comment: For parsing XML, take a look at the Groovy XmlSlurper class. You don't need it here now. The parameters you are looking for are the basic ones and they are easy to get in Groovy. I've edited my answer with how to do that.

Comment: Thanks so much. That is super useful! I believe I have checked off this question as answered, but if there's anything more I can do in that area, please let me know.

Comment: I needed to form a list of the params. Using your answer, and fooling around a bit, I came up with: `def param_names = params.collect{ it.name}`